# Java 12 Shell not reading keyboard input properly on Windows

Tags: java, jshell, java-12

Has the Java Shell changed the way it reads keyboard input in Java 12? It sometimes misses keystrokes, and the arrow keys often print random letters instead  of bringing up the previous line. This is happening in Java 12 using Oracle's OpenJDK on Windows 7.

Comment: You might want to update with the steps to reproduce. Otherwise, it's even tough to judge if you're dealing with an incorrect configuration or is it really an issue.

Comment: @Naman the steps to reproduce are literally just to type `"C:\Program Files\java\jdk-12\bin\jshell"` in a Command Prompt window and then type some text into the shell. You'll see that if you type "2.2" quickly, it may sometimes come out as "22" instead. And then the up arrow may sometimes produce "OA" or some similar random letters.

Comment: and I was thinking that my keyboard was broken... very easy to reproduce. the up arrow problem is not just sometimes, more like very often.

Comment: Yes. JShell in JDK version 12 is broken! One cannot describe the strange behaviour it exhibits when one tries to use the up/down arrow to recall typed commands/expressions, in any other way. IT'S GOT A BUG, PERIOD! So, as temporary work-around, I am currently sticking with the JShell in my JDK 11 (which I run side-by-side with JDK 12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. JShell in JDK version 12 seems to broken! As one cannot describe the strange behavior that it exhibits when one tries to use the up/down arrow to recall previously typed/executed commands/expressions, in any other way. IT'S GOT A BUG, PERIOD! So, as temporary work-around, I recommend sticking with the JShell in JDK 11 (if you have that installed/running side-by-side with your JDK 12).

Comment: It seems to be behaving much better in the latest Java 12.0.2.